# Android Intent doesn't seem to be working - help required!

Tags: android, android-intent

So my situation is this. I have two tables, e.g. employee and department. When a new employee is made, there is a spinner which is populated from the departments database, when this is selected it inserts it in to a field in the employee table.

What I am trying to do is have a list of departments and once the department is clicked, it shows all employee's that belong to that department.

So heres what I have so far, the first code is from my class which displays the department list:

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long empDept) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, empDept);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EmployeeActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(DatabaseAdapter.DEPT_NAME, empDept);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_START); 
    }
```

I am passing this to the employee list activity, I have tested the code by just displaying everything so it is working to some extent but when I am trying to view by the selected dept name it returns nothing, here is the section of the class that receives the intent:

```
private void fillData() {

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        long result = extras.getLong("empDept");

        Cursor empCursor= DbHelper.getEmpByDept(result);

        startManagingCursor(empCursor);
```

And here is my database query:

```
 public Cursor getEmpByDept(long empDept)
 {
     return mDb.query(EMP_TABLE, new String[] { EMP_ID, EMP_TITLE,
                EMP_NOTES, EMP_DATE_TIME, EMP_DEPT }, EMP_DEPT + "=" + empDept, null,
                null, null, null, null);
 }
```

So what I'm trying to do is just show the employees when the department clicked matches what is in the employees EMP_DEPT field.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I would check that `DatabaseAdapter.DEPT_NAME` really equals "empDept".

Comment: How would I go about checking whats being passed through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `extras.getLong()` the input is the key of the bundle, that is `DatabaseAdapter.DEPT_NAME` and not `"empDept"`. Also make sure that `DatabaseAdapter.DEPT_NAME`, the key, includes a proper package prefix as indicated in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20long%29).

btw.: you don't need the last null in the query which is optional and refers to LIMIT (if you don't have one)

Comment: I've changed this and it gives no error but still has the same result of not returning any data. Any further help is appreciated - is it correct to be in onListItemClick or should it be in onActivityResult?

Comment: @user319940 check what value result is and whether it was the actual long that you gave in. If result is 0L then the mapping is not correct. It's OK, you must put in `onListItemClick`

Comment: Of course, if the mapping is correct then the actual long hasn't any correspondence with a department id. If the mapping isn't working check which keys you have in the bundle with keySet()

Comment: Thanks for your help, how do I check what value it is passing?

Comment: If you're using eclipse with the adt plugin you can use the built-in [debugger](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html) Otherwise that page also tells how to debug in other environments. Vote up is appreciated :)

Comment: I've been using this but can't see where it shows what values have been passed?

Comment: did you follow this tutorial? http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-extra-credit.html  Once you're in the debugger perspective you select the variables you want, right click and watch Check the variables tab

Comment: So when i've looked, "empDept" is outputting the position (id) instead of the name - how would I resolve this?

Comment: Ok, I got it :D there was an error in my database schema too but what you put is basically the correct answer. Thanks a bunch!